# How to derive the 'addresses' field on an output from a serialized tx

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, json-rpc

I'm trying to figure out how to derive the addresses field from a serialized tx. Take for instance this transaction on the test network

`46993a02c0f271e8106159581fd2329d46818b9888b5123290c5d1da1718b8b9`

The serialized format for this tx is

`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`

the json format is this:

```
{
    "hex" : "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",
    "txid" : "46993a02c0f271e8106159581fd2329d46818b9888b5123290c5d1da1718b8b9",
    "version" : 1,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "vin" : [
        {
            "txid" : "71d85197037a7760fdf7a1b42861e26234758cf7485cbb27911ccbe0b07e0eb9",
            "vout" : 1,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "0 3045022100c2602e5f6bb2a0df006f734493a404f491abade27f2c1a9d0c7c7fd249de00b20220111b273b653dc2d0ec890e10d89d7e7a095fd88e27e588f5a60ba5d80ad3c8bb01 3045022100cc574b83104238d94e8c6abda28d33ce2377c324263bfa62ce6f240fa60356fb0220117970c87c00169630f5f368bf90f0f11ea156a7befdab0299ee4f3577a229ed01 5221031d1f0c5147b30190cc837b180c2e2a09733f4fd5d146809091950a80383e92682103bb7f1955df8f9b52bfaa908a0e968ad019ef5e8b832ae405e6d882aeda10ec5321028ea4acd57ae1abd53260b32d252472691ea4402d9ac9d4d0fb8fb4636544a4d453ae",
                "hex" : "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"
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid" : "71d85197037a7760fdf7a1b42861e26234758cf7485cbb27911ccbe0b07e0eb9",
            "vout" : 0,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "0 3045022100b922b6495ce11ab5b8959e0fb97a40bc98011d32b81ece252f2d3bfaf3c34ccf0220194951276272a21c7c0e001d26e68ca9a532927c0c703902ac96a4933824b0e101 3044022100dd7bbfba7d765843580d158bf9ef92ba34798d82a42e0098b8acd229cfd6afc3021f55d516e1913bbce390e6fd251d4da483a05e7cb8e510a02f9c6e2d92e574da01 522103e9b16e8ef73855ffa479d7c1b655f99d6834003c6608210b575a0c6bc6c062632103f12e2f8a3357ba47e8ea91b5ce2325dbc9346e4d2bf8db5d30f9422201bc320e210392a98eb30cb3840e47b3b081f43508da37e499272ede8c95f27b9afca813257953ae",
                "hex" : "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"
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [
        {
            "value" : 0.00240000,
            "n" : 0,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_HASH160 5868dadcf00a6fff4cc54752e6e75b046d24aad6 OP_EQUAL",
                "hex" : "a9145868dadcf00a6fff4cc54752e6e75b046d24aad687",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "scripthash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "2N1Jh4cYEFPvw43kZaJovks3hwMWFRUdJ9E"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.11055498,
            "n" : 1,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_HASH160 d81e64eb5a16486b3b5b9dc14eda3412e40ca863 OP_EQUAL",
                "hex" : "a914d81e64eb5a16486b3b5b9dc14eda3412e40ca86387",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "scripthash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "2NCwxMYedhG73QXxDC8jDXY9i5mw4KGcAqo"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "blockhash" : "0000000000000fc2902d17140996a27be5d9dfaf8480ea786fa83dc656da72ca",
    "confirmations" : 10,
    "time" : 1452693415,
    "blocktime" : 1452693415
}
```

I'm looking through the [developer guide examples](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format), and it does not seem like the `addresses` field on the vout's are actually serialized. The same thing is true for `reqSigs`. How are they being derived for the transaction if they are not explicitly serialized inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields you are looking for, `addresses` and `reqSigs`, are indeed serialized in the transaction. In particular, they are implied by the `scriptPubKey` binary string.

The `scriptPubKey` field is very general, supporting many payment types and even arbitrary garbage data (unfortunately).

The format for pay-to-pubkey-hash (P2PKH) is `<OP_DUP> <OP_HASH160> <push 20-byte pubKeyHash> <OP_EQUALVERIFY> <OP_CHECKSIG>` [[source]](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address_.28pay-to-pubkey-hash.29). The 20-byte hash is converted via Base58Check into the address string. And as per the documentation you linked to, `reqSigs` is 1 for P2PKH.

Another format for the script is a bare multisig, and this will allow `reqSigs` to be greater than 1.

Note that the JSON data is produced by a function named `DecodeRawTransaction`. This is why the output data seems to be different from the input data, because additional processing and interpretation was performed on it.